# Angularjs - How to redirect two different link to same page but show different data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to create following type of UI in angularjs

IN menu there are two button: New User and My profile.

Menu is in header.html

New user redirect to mypage.html

My profile redirect to mypage.html

Both New user and my profile have same ui, they have Name and Gender text both.

If user click on newuser then textbox should be blank and if user click on myprofile then it should show user details and hide the blank textbox.

I try to achieve this but on refresh it gives error and it takes two click while I click on my profile to show my profile details.

Comment: did you tried ng-if directive?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: There is no any error. That is why I am confused, why such thing happening. @NehaSaggam

Comment: *"I try to achieve this but on refresh it gives error" ... "There is no any error. That is why I am confused"*... If I wasn't confused, I certainly am now! Can you post some code @Mohammed?

Comment: check my answer it will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My understanding :**

[image]

**Implementation as per my understanding :**

On click of `New User` and `My Profile` pass some `param` in the routing path that will define which action you are performing.

**Html :**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ui-sref="myPage({action: 'newuser'})">New User</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ui-sref="myPage({action: 'myprofile'})">My Profile</a>
```

**routing :**

```
.state('mypage', {
    url: '/mypage/:action',
    templateUrl: 'mypage.html',
    controller: 'myPageCtrl'
})
```

**URL after routing :**

```
http://www.example.com/mypage/newuser (on `New User` icon click)
http://www.example.com/mypage/myprofile (on `My Profile` icon click)
```

**myPageCtrl Controller :**

```
$scope.userAction = $stateParam.action; // newuser or myprofile
```

Now, You can put `ng-if` in the mypage.html based on the `$scope.userAction` value.

Comment: You means in my mypage.html. I will check the userAction value in ng-if. And if its newuser then it wll show newuser else it it will show my profile.If its right then can I use ng-show instead of ng-if? @Rohit

Comment: Yes you understand correctly. You can also use ng-show.

Comment: And is this possible with .when parameter of angualrjs instead of .state parameter? Actually I had used .when parameter of $routePram @Rohit

Comment: It means I don't need to do change syntax for routeParam just replace .state with .when. If yes then thanks bro..its working like champ..u rocked. @Rohit